# Chrome not submitting POST request to server

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am having trouble with Chrome not submitting POST/GET form requests with various PHP applications we use internally to my company. This seems to have started with Chrome 76. The problem does not occur with Firefox or IE which is odd.

The behavior expected when a form is submitted is to see the request in the Dev Network console while it waits for a response from the server. But in Chrome, the request is never sent or seen in the Network console. The Chrome progress wheel in the tab just spins counter-clockwise forever.

I have checked the Apache request logs on the server and it never gets a request sent to it so I am thinking it is something on the client side, i.e. Chrome.

If I try and submit the form manually using Postman, then it will work and send the expected response.

I have tried using JavaScript to submit the form but I am seeing the same behavior. I have tried changing the enctype of the form as well as adjusting the meta tag headers but no change.

Headers

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="xxxx">
```

Form

```
<form method="POST" action="https://homestead.test/login">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="xxxx">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Username</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" required autofocus>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">Remember Me</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to better debug form submissions on the client-side? Is there some check that Chrome does before sending a HTTP request that the other browsers don't do and is failing? Is there a way to completely reload/reset Chrome in case it is an errant setting? Incognito mode should be loading without any extensions and it is behaving the same so I don't think it is a rogue extension causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **your php server** add the following line on **your header file**

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

should be in all pages you want to receive the post requests

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
```

As you are sending post data from a local server to a remote server, you will need to enable **CORS - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing** on your remote server.

This code should work for most of the cases, test and tell me if it's solved.

Comment: Set these headers and added the mod_headers CORS config settings in Apache but still no change

Comment: try with  `method="GET"` maybe it's a chrome issue with post method

Comment: can you also inspect console and tell me what it shows to you?

Comment: GET method doesn't work either. When trying to submit the form via JavaScript, I'm printing to the console and I see the print statements before and after the $('#loginForm').submit(); but the request never gets sent. No errors get printed

Comment: Chrome just updated and it looks like the issue might be fixed. Continuing testing

Comment: so it was the Chrome version?

Comment: I think so. I'm updated to version 76.0.3809.132 (64-bit) and the issue has gone away